# Происхождение фразеологизма

Tags: фразеология

Когда говорят о том, что человек хочет слишком многого, говорят, что он "раскатал губу". А откуда пошло это выражение?

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происхождение фразеологизмов разговорного характера зачастую недостоверно. Употребленное раз образное выражение повторяется, передается из поколение в поколение. Можно, конечно, строить предположения. Например. такое: когда мы чем-то увлечены, нам очень интересно (хочется еще и еще) - рот приоткрывается, нижняя губа отвисает. Вот кто-то когда-то в такой момент и выдал такую метафору. Но, возможно, кто-то знает точный ответ или другие предположения?

Answer (score 1):

Точной этимологии нет, но очевидно, что губа здесь - гриб. А раскатать предположительно - тесто. Грибные пироги у простонародья всегда считались деликатесом и верхом пирожного искусства.

Повторюсь, это всего лишь предположения. Но в грибах я уверен. Дело в том, что словарями фиксируются выражения "раскатать пельмени" (примерно в том же значении и ещё конкретно на женщину), а "раскатать губы" на фене - начать разговаривать, давать показания. 
Первый пример объясняет "раскатать", второй - невозможность прямого значения "губы".