# "Раскатать губу" — происхождение поговорки

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Когда-то давно в "Что? Где? Когда?" был вопрос о происхождении этой поговорки.
И тогда дали ответ, который показался мне о-о-о-очень спорным:
*дрессировщик, засовывая голову в пасть льва, как-то так кладет его губы, что тот не может закрыть пасть, не поранившись.*

По-моему, это плод чьей-то бурной фантазии. Или нет?

Comment: См. также https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, вообще-то это не русский фразеологизм (в списке русских фразологизмов его нет). Это, по Вашкевичу, [идиома-калька](http://nnvashkevich.narod.ru/kng/IZBRIDIOM.htm).

ГУБА2, губы раскатать – ♦ В словарях (Ожегов, ФСРЯ, ФРФ) не отмечено. Означает "возыметь желание получить то, что мало доступно".  Первая часть от арабского  أعجوبة 'уъгу:ба "то, что нравится", вторая – от رسخت расахат "утвердиться", прочитанного в обратном направлении:  تخسر тахсар "проиграть", "потерять". Буквально: "утвердиться в том, что нравится, но потерять",  т.е. "сильно захотеть, но потерять" (арабское письмо читается справа налево, а прочитали, как европейское, - слева).

Фразеологическое калькирование в ряде случаев приводит к возникновению таких
русских сочетаний слов, в которых синтаксические связи и семантические
отношения слов не соответствует существующим в русском языке правилам и
законам и вызывает развитие новых переносных значений и моделей фразеологизмов уже на родной почве, отсюда "закатай губу".

Интересно, что в прямом смысле раскатать губу, оказывается, [возможно](http://shaman-michael.livejournal.com/585158.html).

Comment: По мне версия какая-то за уши притянутая. Напрямую с арабами мы не общались, а через персов, татар и османов, выражение могло пройти, только если оно есть в Коране, общаются они всё-таки на других языках. С таким же успехом, можно выражение к африканским женщиам привязать.

Comment: У нас много калькированных фразеологизмов, в том числе арабских. Мы же не знаем, когда оно к нам пришло, не обязательно в далёкой давности. А общаться мы с ними давно общаемся , и достаточно активно. Попробуйте исследовать, когда появилось и как, если докажете автору этимологического словаря обратное - мы Вас поддержим, а пока я верю учёному: он этим занимается профессионально, а я  философствующий дилетант.

Comment: Я привык проверять. А с арабами, я как историк могу свидетельствовать, наши контакты, века до XIX были минимальными. Кстати по поводу данного сочинения академик РАН лингвист А. Зализняк со мной [согласен](http://www.gazeta.ru/science/2011/12/02_a_3855010.shtml).

 Цитирую академика, - "Классической пример любительской лингвистики. Трудно сказать, представляет ли автор вообще, как подобного рода превращение одного языка в другой могло произойти в реальности".

Comment: Ну, Зализняк сам иногда "оригинальничает".Вашкевич,конечно, с его идеей общего арабского корня "загнул", как и Герасимов, утверждающий, что АРАБСКИЙ – ЭТО ДРЕВНЕРУССКИЙ, застывший на периферии цивилизации,как и Чудинов. Но вообще-то у них не всё такая уж ерунда. Вспоминается ещё и Лев Гумилёв с его идеей происхождения Руси, и многие другие, доказывающие , что древний санскрит  – это древнерусский язык, сохранившийся в  северном поморском наречии. Дальние - то предки у нас были одни (от Адама).А кто из учёных прав, кто не прав - потом выяснится.Фасмер же объясняет некоторые слова из арабского.

Comment: Арабский - это даже не индоевропейский язык. Общего с русским там практически нет. Арабские слова есть в русском, но появлялись они не напрямую от арабов, а опосредовано, через Западную Европу, или через мусульман на южных границах России. Слово подобным путём проникнуть может, но фразеологизм - только в том случае, если он имел сакральный смысл (фраза богослужения), что судя по всему, не так

Да и предположение, что в эпоху всеобщей безграмотности появляется новое устойчивое выражение от того, что некто одно арабское слово прочитал справа-налево, а второе слева-направо, по-моему, абсурдно.

Answer (score 4):

В данном случае, по-моему, чем проще тем лучше.

Что такое "раскатать губу"? Необоснованно хотеть слишком много. Какое выражение лица от несбывшихся ожиданий? Примерно такое:

[image]

Какие губы у мальчика? Именно, что раскатанные. У детей 3-8 лет такое выражение лица я замечал нередко, - "Купи шоколадку, а то расплачусь", а  мама ему, - "Ишь, губу-то раскатал!". Вряд ли дети наших предков в этом отличались от детей современных.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос о самой поговорке рассматривался на этом форуме здесь: [Происхождение фразеологизма](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5004/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Мне кажется, что вариант со львами не очень правдоподобный. Есть еще такой же "аттракцион" с крокодилами, но у этих рептилий с губами сложности.

Что касается самой поговорки, то ее значение - желать что-то чужое, польститься на чужое. Иногда используют вариант: "Раскатал губу, закатай обратно".  Близко к "На чужой кусок не разевай роток".

Раскатывают обычно тесто. Раскатать губу - оттопырить, сделать так, чтоб губа "отвисла"

Answer (score 2):

Мой отец так объяснил мне происхождение выражения "губки раскатала": в те времена, когда не было косметики и силикона, девушка перед тем, как идти на свидание (целоваться), круговыми движениями руки раскатывала губы , чтобы они стали красными и припухлыми.

Answer (score 1):

У меня такое ощущение, что изначально тут имелась в виду губа женская, которая во время возбуждения "раскатывается".

Answer (score 1):

Про львов - даже не обсуждается. Современный ЧГК я даже перестал смотреть, никакой критики не выдерживает.

Каким боком тут арабский - это тоже надо у доктора спрашивать.
Источник никакого доверия не внушает. Я сталкивался с творениями подобных задорновых-фоменок от лингвистики, они что хочешь через "задом наперед" объяснят.

А по сути... 
Думаю, "губа" здесь впролне русское слово и означает "гриб". Такое значение фиксируется многими словарями, особенно - диалектными. Раскатать (закатать) губу - приготовить грибной пирог (начинку и тесто).

Answer (score 1):

Даль приводит поговорки :

> У него молоко на губах не
> обсохло, молокосос.
> **Распустить губы**, зевать,
> ротозеить.
> Прикусить (закусить) губу,
> замолчать.
> Надуть губы, дуться, гневаться.
> Что летом ногой приволочишь, то зимой
> губами подберешь.
> Твоим бы медком да нас по
> губам!
> Подбери губы-те : городничий едет!
> Не на мать, губы-то
> надувать!
> Гостя
> потчуй, покуда через губы не перенесет, более
> не сможет.
> **Губа не дура, язык не лопатка:
> знает, что горько, что сладко**.
> Только по губам
> помазал, посулил.
> Умный поп хоть губами
> шевели, а мы, грешные, смекай!
> Не мокра бы
> губка, была б и шубка, пьяница.
> Не срубишь
> дуба, не отдув губы.
> Губы чешутся целоваться.

Выражение **у тебя губа не дура** практически точно соответствует новому, отмеченному в Нацкорпусе семидесятыми годами прошлого века, советскому фразеологизму *раскатать губы* (на что-нибудь).
Арабская версия Вашкевича - бред сумасшедшего ученого.

Российское развитие советского фразеологизма :

> Людмила Петрушевская. Морские помойные рассказы // «Октябрь», 2001   Акулы заметались, **раскатали пасти** и рванули чавкать.

Дополнение.
Сначала не обратил внимание на выражение *распустить губы* (см. Даль). Однако "распустить губы в улыбке" могло иметь вот такое значение :

> Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Золотуха (1883)  Вот в Филиппов пост свадьбу будем играть. Фомка-то **давно на нее губы распустил**… Молодайка, жена Никиты, не принимала участия в общем разговоре, шутках и смехе; как только последние лопатки песку были промыты, она сейчас же бегом убежала в сторону леса, где стоял балаган Зайца.

*Распустить губы на кого/что* ~~~ *раскатать губы на лакомый кусочек*. Стало быть, истоки сегодняшнего популярного фразеологизма - давнишние, оно только чуть-чуть поменяло форму.

Answer (score 0):

В старые времена пекли калачи. Перед выпечкой разрезали заготовку калача и засыпали мукой. Эта ***губа*** разворачивалась при выпекании. Позже обсыпали сахаром или сахарной пудрой.
*Раскатать губу* — желать невозможного (ведь сахаром присыпать перестали).